# How do I use BASH to change "A" Train.flac to 'A' Train in a filename?

Tags: bash, script

I've tried every combination of backslash and asterisk and curly brackets, nothing seems to work. I'm using the terminal in OS X and I would really appreciate it if someone could steer me straight.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you changing the " into ', and/or removing the .flac? Are you trying to make this a bulk command, or just this one file?

Comment: My humble thanks to STATUS__ACCESS. This started as Windows not liking the " on a Mac OS X networked drive, probably due to some changes in Lion. I figured (wrongly) that this would be an opportunity to learn more about BASH scripting with a quick rename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `$()` in order to task `tr` to do that conversion, then strip the file extension in a second step. It would look something similar to:

```
# Say FNAME is the variable that stores your original file name
# Convert the double quotes to single quotes:
SQFNAME=$(echo $FNAME|tr '""' "''")
# or, as an alternative in pure Bash (mind the shell character escaping):
SQFNAME=echo ${FNAME//\"/\'}
# then simply strip the extension
NEWFNAME=${SQFNAME%.flac}
# or, if you wanted to remove the extension delimited by the _last_ dot
NEWFNAME=${SQFNAME%.*}
# or, if you wanted to remove the extension delimited by the _first_ dot
NEWFNAME=${SQFNAME%%.*}
```

The "new" converted file name will be in the `NEWFNAME` variable now.

---

Proof of concept:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
FNAME="\"A\" Train.flac"
echo "Unchanged name: $FNAME"
SQFNAME=${FNAME//\"/\'}
echo "Converted quotes: $SQFNAME"
NEWFNAME=${SQFNAME%.flac}
echo "New file name: $NEWFNAME"
```

Execution yields:

```
$ bash test.sh
Unchanged name: "A" Train.flac
Converted quotes: 'A' Train.flac
New file name: 'A' Train
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `prename` Perl script that comes with most Perl installations (linked to `rename` in e.g. Debian based distributions, but on e.g. Fedora another `rename` is present, so research the case first if you are not sure, or just use `prename` as below):

```
prename 's/"/'\''/g' \"A\"\ Train.flac
```

The right tool for the right job.

To get a literal `'`, I first stop the current quoting environment, then escape a `'`, then start the quoting environment again.

---

I guess you don't really want to strip the file name extension and the question is just ambiguously worded, but if you do:

```
prename 's/"/'\''/g; s/\..*$//' \"A\"\ Train.flac
```

or

```
prename 's/"/'\''/g; s/\.flac$//' \"A\"\ Train.flac
```

Use the `-n` switch to just view the changes without applying them if you want to test the commands beforehand.